# How to do a match in R with left_join using multiple columns and one "likely" column

Tags: r, left-join

Im triying to do a match between two different data frames in R.

For example one data frame looks like:

```
df1<- data.frame(description=c("sol 100ml","200 mg","1.5 ml","10MG"),
                 pa=c("clorbetazol","Milk","Aciclovir","AAC"),
                 atc=c("x1","a2","a3","x3"))

 description          pa atc
   sol 100ml clorbetazol  x1
      200 mg        Milk  a2
      1.5 ml   Aciclovir  a3
        10MG         AAC  x3
```

And the other one looks like:

```
df2 <-data.frame(Concentration=c("100","200","1.5","10"),
                 pa=c("clorbetazol","Milk","Aciclovir","AAC"),
                 atc=c("x1","a2","a3","x3"),
                 code=c("A101","A202","A303","A404"))

  Concentration          pa atc code
            100 clorbetazol  x1 A101
            200        Milk  a2 A202
            1.5   Aciclovir  a3 A303
             10         AAC  x3 A404
```

My question is: There is a way to do a match with columns "pa", "atc" and use "concentration" column in some way (use GREPL or something) to do left join o merge?

Finally i want to get this:

```
 description          pa atc  code
   sol 100ml clorbetazol  x1  A101
      200 mg        Milk  a2  A202
      1.5 ml   Aciclovir  a3  A303
        10MG         AAC  x3  A404
```

I wonder if someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the numbers, which you then match with a left join:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = gsub("^.*?(\\d+(\\.)?(\\d+)?).*$", "\\1", description)) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("pa", "atc", "Concentration")) %>%
  select(-Concentration)
#>   description          pa atc code
#> 1   sol 100ml clorbetazol  x1 A101
#> 2      200 mg        Milk  a2 A202
#> 3      1.5 ml   Aciclovir  a3 A303
#> 4        10MG         AAC  x3 A404
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` with a regex, then `merge`.

```
res <- merge(transform(df1, Concentration=gsub("[^\\d\\.]", "",
                                               description, perl=TRUE)),
      df2, all=TRUE)[-3]
res
#            pa atc description code
# 1         AAC  x3        10MG A404
# 2   Aciclovir  a3      1.5 ml A303
# 3 clorbetazol  x1   sol 100ml A101
# 4        Milk  a2      200 mg A202
```